# No CSS or JS in Magento 2.3.3 on Virtualbox/Vagrant in Windows 7 Host - Text File Busy

Tags: magento2.3, css, permissions, windows, vagrant

I have a Magento 2.3.3-p1 installed in VirtualBox/Vagrant guest on a Windows 7 host. The server setup is running Ubuntu 19.10 with Apache2, PHP 7.3 MYSQL, etc. Despite all my efforts I can only get both the front end and admin sites to load without any CSS or JS. Whenever I try to run the di:compile and deploy static content I get the below warning message as well as many more of the same but for different directories:

```
The Directory "/var/www/html/generated/..." cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(var/www/html/generated/...): Text file busy
```

The closest guess I can make is that Windows 7 is not allowing permissions on the files despite me giving them. I have tried many things but so far no luck.

Please forgive any mistakes or breaches of etiquette here, this is not my usual area as I'm a designer not a programmer.

Update: I have also installed a Wordpress site in the same directory and it is working fine so it just seems to be an issue with Magento 2.

Comment: Remove the generated directory manually and after that try to execute the command on an Administrator command prompt if it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Bhaumik1987 but I tried that already, it just results in: The directory "/var/ww/html... /generated/code" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/var/ww/html... /generated/code): Text file busy

Comment: Try to run the simple static deploy before you run the compilation. 1. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and then 2. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. Check if it works!

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: hi @Bhaumik-1987 sorry but these do not work, I have tried multiple times to do static first, then di:compile and vice-versa but always getting the same result - Text File Busy etc.

Comment: I can log in to the admin section and the images are showing up on the main site - it is just the CSS and JS not getting created.